# Postgis AddGeometryColumn for WKT with different types i.e. Polygon and Multipolygon

Tags: postgis, geometry, well-known-text

I have some polygon data

```
first;1;MULTIPOLYGON (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)), ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))
second;2;POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))
third;3;POLYGON ((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10), (20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))
```

and points

```
1,30,10
2,30,10
3,40,20
4,40,30
5,20,20
6,21,21
```

For these

```
CREATE TABLE polygons (
  id            CHARACTER VARYING(50),
  value            INT,
  geo                 TEXT
);
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE TABLE points (
  id  CHARACTER VARYING(50),
  lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lng DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

Then points are prepared like

```
COPY points (id, lat, lng)
FROM '/dataFiles/samples/points_sample.csv'
WITH
DELIMITER AS ','
CSV HEADER;

-- Add point geometry column to table
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'points', 'geom', 900913, 'POINT', 2);

-- Populate column with point geometries
UPDATE points
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 900913);

-- Create a spatial index on points
CREATE INDEX idx_points
  ON points USING GIST (geom);

VACUUM ANALYZE points;
```

for the polygons I use

```
COPY polygons (sitename, db_range,geo)
FROM '/dataFiles/samples/geometry_sample.csv'
WITH
DELIMITER AS ';'
CSV HEADER;
```

However, when trying to convert to a geometry column I run into the following problem:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'polygons', 'geom', 900913, 'WKT', 2);
```

will not take `WKT` but rather only `POLYGON` or `MULTIPOLYGON`. How should such a column be processed?  To not have the statement below fail?

```
UPDATE polygons
SET geomW = ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(geo), 900913);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to combine two steps into one.
Your SQL here is only for [adding a new geometry column](http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) to your Polygons table:
`SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'polygons', 'geom', 900913, 'WKT', 2);`

That column has to have one of the recognized geometry types, Point, LineString, Polygon, etc.  You are attempting to have it accept 'WKT', which is not an geometry type, but a "text markup language for representing said geometry", from Wikipedia [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

What you need to do, is create your geometry column with a recognized geometry type, like:
`SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'polygons', 'geom', 900913, 'POLYGON', 2);`
`SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'polygons', 'geom', 900913, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 2);`

**EDIT**
To be clear, when you are adding the geometry column, you only choose one geometry type.  If you have both MultiPolygon and Polygon geometry, you will need to cast them one way or the other.

---

When you update your table, you will do the conversion from `WKT` to the database encoding. Assume your geometry column is `MultiPolygon`.  Use `ST_Multi` to cast your data.  Data already in **Multi** format will remain as such:

```
UPDATE polygons
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromText(geo)), 900913);
```

Hat tip to @Underdark with her answer to:  [How to convert/typecast from Polygon to MultiPolygon in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/how-to-convert-typecast-from-polygon-to-multipolygon-in-postgis)

Comment: but for me it was not possible to call AddGeometryColumn twice on the same column (here geom) with different WKT types. Should this really work?

Comment: See edit to my answer.  Short version:  Choose one, then cast your data to one geom type or the other.